# Shortcode attributes that query the database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a shortcode that returns a list of doctors matching a specialty.

So far, I can get the base shortcode to return the contents of the entire table, but I can't get it to query based on an attribute string.

Here's what I have:

```
// Add Shortcode
function list_docs( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'specialty' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'doctors'
    );

    global $wpdb;
    $specialty = $atts['specialty'];
    $specget = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE specialty = '%s'", $specialty);
    $specresults = $wpdb->get_results($specget);

    foreach($specresults as $details) {
        echo $details;
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'doctors', 'list_docs' );
```

If I query the database directly with:

```
SELECT * FROM `doctors` WHERE `specialty` = 'cardiology'
```

I get the expected result.

I'm trying to call it with `[doctors specialty="cardiology"]` (I've tried double and single quotes) on the WordPress page.

Right now, I don't know what I don't know.  I'm not sure if I've entered something wrong, have a typo, or am missing a line of code.  Any assistance would be terrific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be problem is not with the query at all assuming that your table name is indeed `doctors`( & not `wp_doctors` or something like that )

`$specresults` will contain an array of objects. Let's say your `doctors` table has `name` column, then below changes may work for you.

```php
function list_docs( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'specialty' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'doctors'
    );

    global $wpdb;
    $specialty   = $atts['specialty'];
    $specget     = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE specialty = %s', $specialty );
    $specresults = $wpdb->get_results( $specget );

    if ( $specresults ) {
        $doctor_names = array_map(
            function( $doctor_object ) {
                return $doctor_object->name;
            },
            $specresults
        );
        return implode( ', ', $doctor_names );
    }

    return '';

}
add_shortcode( 'doctors', 'list_docs' );
```

Couple of things to keep in mind:-

1. Shortcodes should always return & not echo directly.
2. Query only for required data from the database as far as possible instead of doing *
3. If you are going to need only one column, prefer using `get_col` method on `$wpdb` instead of `get_results`.

Comment: Thanks Sumit.  That fixed it.  Your solution showed me what my own was missing.  I solved it slightly different from your answer, but definitely swapped out the echo for return.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this -

```
function list_docs( $atts ) {

    global $wpdb;
        $specialty = $atts['specialty'];
        $specget = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE specialty = %s", $specialty);
        $specresults = $wpdb->get_results($specget);

        foreach($specresults as $details) {
        echo $details;
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'doctors', 'list_docs' );
```

Comment: No luck with that.  I think you have to declare $atts as an array, but I may be wrong.